# SQL Server: selecting primary key number for a newly added row

Tags: sql-server, select, identity

I'm currently using

```
SELECT MAX(CustomerID)...
```

to select the `CustomerID`, which is the primary key of the table, number of a newly added row because I need to use this number for another table that uses it as a foreign key. One row is added via `INSERT`, and one `SELECT` query is performed sequentially.

Under column property in SQL Server Management Studio, I see the `Identity Increment` is set to `1`. Is there an unsafe reason to use `MAX(CustomerID)` to get what I need? The code will always be "one row INSERT and one SELECT queries" for this procedure. If there is a better way, what would that be? Perhaps, somewhere along the line, "get me the `CustomerID` of the newly added row"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested approach with `MAX(CustomerID)` will fail under conditions of concurrency (and when the table is empty)

use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or the `OUTPUT` clause. Examples of both below

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers
(
CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Customers
(Name) 
VALUES ('Customer 1')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO #Customers
(Name) 
OUTPUT inserted.CustomerID
VALUES ('Customer 1')


DROP TABLE #Customers
```

Comment: you are spot on with this and thank you so much for the example as well! I tested SECOPE_IDENTITY, and it works great. Regarding when it fails, under the procedural queries I've described, would I ever run into an "empty table" problem? Also, the "conditions of concurrency" you mentioned is referring to concurrent DB connections?

Comment: @user796837 - `MAX(CustomerID)` would be `NULL` when there are no rows in the table yet. Obviously only applies if you are doing the check before the insert however and is easy enough to get around that though with `ISNULL`. The main issue is concurrent DB connections. As there is no guarantee that another row won't get inserted by another connection in between you doing the `insert` and checking the `MAX` in which case you would be bringing back the `id` for the wrong row.